# Узнать загрузилась ли страница в iframe

Tags: iframe

Есть iframe в котором грузится страница другого ресурса, 
но которая может быть запрещена грузиться в iframe по причине security-content-policy или x-frame-origin и т.д.
Как узнать что она не загрузилась по какой-либо причие?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];//или getElementsBy()

iframe.onload = function() {
   alert( "iframe onload" );
};
```

Вот [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/iframes) есть еще кое-какая информация на эту тему - м.б. поможет

Answer (score 0):

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
    $(this).contents().html("Ы!");
});
```